# Syntax error while running shell script via Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

While executing the run command, I'm getting syntax error as follows:

```
 > [10/10] RUN ./download_files.sh:
#15 0.285 ./download_files.sh: 5: ./download_files.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./download_files.sh]: exit code: 2
```

The Shell script contents are as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir pretrained_models
cd pretrained_models
declare -a StringArray=("https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/BC-DeepLIIF_Training_Set.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/BC-DeepLIIF_Validation_Set.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/DeepLIIF_BC_Model.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/DeepLIIF_Latest_Model.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/DeepLIIF_Testing_Set.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/DeepLIIF_Training_Set.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/DeepLIIF_Validation_Set.zip" "https://zenodo.org/record/4751737/files/Evaluation_Excel_Files.zip")
for val in ${StringArray[@]}; do
   exec wget $val
done
```

Comment: `declare -a StringArray=(...)` is not supported in `sh`, but it is in `bash` for example, or just  `StringArray=(...)`.

Comment: More general: sh does not have arrays at all.

Comment: You should also remove the `exec` keyword. As written it will **replace** your shell script with the first `wget`.